# Unable to move custom list items from one list to another using server-side object module

Tags: 2013, development, ssom

I have 2 list named "ActiveItems" and "ArchItems". i wrote the following code to move some items from the "ActiveItems" to the "ArchItems":-

```
using (SPSite omsSite = new SPSite("http://****/"))  //site collection url
                {
                    using (SPWeb omsWeb = omsSite.OpenWeb("OrderManagement")) 
                    {
                        SPWebCollection subWebs = omsWeb.Webs;    
                        //query for the alert period
                        SPList sourceomslist = omsWeb.Lists.TryGetList("ActiveItems");

                        foreach (SPListItem currentItem in sourceomslist.Items)
                        {
                          if (!currentItem.ContentType.Name.ToLower().Contains("project"))
                                {
                           Console.WriteLine(currentItem["ID"]);
                           SPFile file = omsWeb.GetFile(currentItem.Url);
                           file.MoveTo(omsWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/ArchItems/" + currentItem.ID.ToString() + "_.000");         

                                }
                        }
```

now i will not get any error, but the list item will not be moved. any idea?

Thanks

Comment: It might be due to you doing the move inside foreach. Can you try just taking first item from the Items array, and moving it without foreach to rule out that is not the issue. Another thing to try is to get hold of the file using GetFileByServerRelativeUrl instead of the Items array.

Comment: @JussiPalo can you please explain your points in more details? why using `foreach` can cause an issue?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that ArchItems is a library not a list as You are trying to move a file to it. If so then the link to a document library is without '/lists'/ because libraries are like 'folders' on web. Please try to change the line

```
    file.MoveTo(omsWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/ArchItems/" + currentItem.ID.ToString() + "_.000");
```

to

```
    file.MoveTo(omsWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchItems/" + currentItem.ID.ToString() + "_.000");
```

... I suppose it should do the trick. If this does not help please surround the code with

```
    try
    {
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("MoveToWhenProjectCT", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
    }
```

... and after a couple of tries check ULS logs form maybe more info about the problem

I hope this will be of any help

Comment: no the ArchItems is custom list !

Comment: ok... maybe You could check if one of the flags will help. the MoveTo method as a second parameter accepts flags: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee542328%28v%3doffice.15%29

maybe this will help.
Is there anything different on the target list that is not present on the source list ? Like different content type configuration or some versioning settings?

Comment: they have the same content type and versioning, actually i saved the first list as template (without content) and created the second list based on the template.

Answer (score 0):

The following example code for your reference.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp2013/sites/team"))
{
    using (SPWeb omsWeb = site.OpenWeb("OrderManagement"))
    {
        SPList sourceomslist = omsWeb.Lists.TryGetList("ActiveItems");
        SPList destList = omsWeb.Lists.TryGetList("ArchItems");
        foreach (SPListItem currentItem in sourceomslist.Items)
        {
            if (!currentItem.ContentType.Name.ToLower().Contains("project"))
            {
                SPListItem newItem = destList.Items.Add();
                foreach (SPField field in currentItem.Fields)
                {
                    if (!field.ReadOnlyField && !field.Hidden && field.InternalName != "Attachments")
                    {
                        if (newItem.Fields.ContainsField(field.InternalName)) {
                            newItem[field.InternalName] = currentItem[field.InternalName];
                        }                                    
                    }
                }
                newItem.Update();
                sourceomslist.GetItemById(currentItem.ID).Delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you mean i need to manually re-create the items, as i have around 25 fields that will need to be mapped in this case

Comment: The code above will create new items in the target list and set the list fields value automatically if the fields exists in the target list. I suggest you use the same list structure for the target list.

Comment: @SharePointTestDev: Do you mean your destination list doesn't already contain the same fields are source list at the time you're doing MoveTo?

Comment: @JussiPalo they contain the same fields and CTs